# Trying to get folder path through file id using appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am pulling a drive activity report using GCP/GAMadv which gives me file IDs of various users in our workspace domain on a google sheet. My goal is to find the folder path of these files using file IDs. I am using appscript to get to that. Here is the code that I am running so far.

```
function getFolderPath(fileID, folderPath =""){
  var sheetID = "1YfZgkLvAnPj7kOIQOVkcXeJgnh-KTecMn6er1a0elkk"
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID)
  // var file = sheet.Files.get(fileID)
  var parent = Drive.Files.get(fileID);
  console.log(parent)
  // console.log(file)
  var parentElement = parent.items[0]

  console.log(parentElement)
  // var parentElement = parent[0]

  var parentFile = Drive.Files.get(parent.id);
  var parentPath = parentFile.title;

  if (parent.isRoot)
  return "/" + folderPath;
  else {
    return getFolderPath(
      parentFile.id,
      parentPath + "/" + folderPath
    );
  }
}
```

Looks like this is returning ALL the files we have in our drive rather than the ones on the sheet.
Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Folder Path from Id

```
function getFolderPathFromId(id="fileid") {
  try {
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id)
    var pA = [];
    pA.push(file.getName());
    var folder = file.getParents();
    while (folder.hasNext()) {
      var f = folder.next();
      pA.push(f.getName());
      folder = f.getParents()
    }
    var r = pA.reverse().slice(0,-1).join(' / ');
  }
  catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
  Logger.log(r);
  return r;
}
```